# Collecting data from instagram using json

Tags: python, json, instagram

I was working on a project that requires data from instagram, i am collecting it using the json.
When i use the test link: http://vocab.nic.in/rest.php/states/json - it works, but when i use: https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1 (also json) - it didn't work.
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 196-197: character maps to

```
import urllib.request
import json

def getResponse(url):
    operUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    if(operUrl.getcode()==200):
        data = operUrl.read()
        jsonData = json.loads(data)
    else:
        print("Error receiving data", operUrl.getcode())
    return jsonData

def main():

    urlData = "https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1"
    jsonData = getResponse(urlData)
    # print the state id and state name corresponding
    print(jsonData)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\andrey_user\Desktop\ig\test.py", line 21, in [module] main()
File "C:\Users\andrey_user\Desktop\ig\test.py", line 18, in main print(jsonData)
File "D:\programs\programing\Python\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 196-197: character maps to [undefined]
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: posted the full Traceback

Comment: What is your `stdout` encoding?(ie, `sys.stdout.encoding`)

Comment: I'm not able to replicate, but you could try decoding the bytes yourself to `UTF-8`. `json.loads(data.decode('UTF-8'))`

Comment: json.loads(data.decode('UTF-8')) still didn't help